# ODOO 10 Invoice Validation

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-10, xml-rpc, ripcord

Been trying to auto validate invoices in odoo 10 via php for a while now with no success. Am using the below php code to validate

```
    <?php

    $url = 'http://localhost:8069';
    $url_auth = $url . '/xmlrpc/2/common';
    $url_exec = $url . '/xmlrpc/2/object';

    $db = 'DATABASE';
    $username = 'Username';
    $password = 'Password';

    require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');
    $common = ripcord::client($url_auth);
    $uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

    $models = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/object");
    $invoice_model = 'account.invoice';
    $id = $models->exec_workflow(
           $db, $uid, $password,
                'account.invoice', 
                'invoice_open',
                2948 //invoice Id
    );



    print_r($id);
```

When I execute the above I get no results. No error message, nothing.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It worked fine in Odoo 9...

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` before any other PHP code and see what it outputs

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Enabling error reporting doesn't give further output. `exec_workflow()` just returns boolean false. I have tried to change `invoice_open` to other values but makes no difference. But I think it might be related to these changes in Odoo v10 - just not sure how that converts to PHP: https://supportuae.wordpress.com/tag/odoo-validate-invoice-from-code/ as well as https://bloopark.de/en_US/blog/the-bloopark-times-english-2/post/odoo-10-workflows-partial-removal-265#blog_content

Answer (score 1):

@ThongNguyenVan gave me the hint I needed. It led me to https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/odoo10-sending-invoice-email-via-xmlrpc-118915 which basically had the Python version of the code I needed. So it will convert to the following PHP code:

`$models->execute($db, $uid, $password, 'account.invoice', 'action_invoice_open', array(2948));`

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `invoice_open` in `account.invoice`, but there is an `action_invoice_open`. Could you check it again?

Ref: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L576

Comment: You might be on to something but I don't know how to call that action/method through XML-RPC in PHP...